# How to log the received SOAP message in Spring Integration

Tags: soap, spring-integration

I have a Web Service based inbound Messaging Gateway configured. I'd like to log the incoming SOAP messages (envelope and all inside it). What would be the best way to do that?

I have tried using a wire tap with logging channel adapter, but don't know a good expression value for it to get the actual SOAP XML out. If the inbound gateway is configured not to extract payload, I will see SaajSoapMessage as payload and DOMSource otherwise. Is there an expression to get the SaajSoapMessage as XML String?

Here's my configuration with which I get to see the toString() of SaajSoapMessage:

```
<int:channel id="request">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" expression="payload" level="DEBUG"/>

<int:channel id="reply"/>
<int-ws:inbound-gateway id="ws-inbound-gateway" request-channel="request" reply-channel="reply"
                        extract-payload="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Integration sits on top of Spring Web Services. SWS has some interceptors that can log the payload and/or envelope...

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/server.html#d5e1416

Answer (score 0):

Spring Web Services offers interceptors you could use.

If you use a marshaller and unmarshaller, the both have listeners that can do something before and after they do the marshalling/unmarshalling.

If you need to capture information that was added to the message before of after the ws-inbound-gateway you can use a service activator.

If you want to make sure you log any exception, then consider a segment gateway, and a service activator in it's message flow.